# How to change the menu color in javafx when it is focused

Tags: java, css, javafx, menu

[image]

This is a menu and when I focus it, it is blue.
How to change the color using CSS?

I tried this:

```
ainmenubar.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: #555555;");
```

But it does not work.

Comment: there are lots and lots of questions about this, you may be new, but sometimes use can use search phrases on stackoverflow search or any search engine you want, and the results will be a blessing, try this now, __"javafx menu focused style"__

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! @Elltz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The looked-up color used for that is `-fx-selection-bar`: try

```
ainmenubar.setStyle("-fx-selection-bar: #555555;");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and the question is solved.